# How to hid title bar of Motif Dialog/widget

Tags: c, linux, motif

How to create a dialog without a `Title bar`. I want to create `motif` dialog/widget using 
`XtVaCreateMangedWidget` and `XtVaCreateWidget` without a title bar and how to create the same dialog full screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved the issue, here is the detail

```
m_wgMainFrm = XtVaAppInitialize(&m_pApp, ...

m_wgMainWnd = XtVaCreateManagedWidget("main_window", ...

m_wgDrawingArea = XtVaCreateWidget("Test",...

XtVaSetValues(m_wgMainFrm, XmNmwmDecorations, (MWM_DECOR_BORDER), NULL);
XtUnmapWidget(m_wgMainFrm);
XtMapWidget(m_wgMainFrm);
```

Comment: Notice that in 6 months you have not accepted any answers from you questions.  Consider upvoting the answers you found useful and accepting the ones you that solved you query.  You can even accept your own.

Comment: I have accepted my previous question by voting up. By the way how can I accept my own answer? always got message `you can't vote for your own post`

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for details about using your own answer.  [See here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) for accepting your own.

Comment: Ah sorry i mixed-up the voting up and accepting the answer. Thanks